# NSURLConnection connectionDidFinishLoading is called before webpage is loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, connection, nsurlconnection

I just started iOS programming and am failing to understand this.. I am trying to connect to a website that has a login.. I am using `NSURLConnection` and POST, and sending my login credentials..

The credentials are right and the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is called but it is not completely logged into the site.. the login is partially complete..I identified this when I looked at the response.. As per my understanding the "connectionDidFinishLoading" is called only after the connection is complete.. I am definitely missing something here.. My code is below.. Please advice..

```
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {
    // Login to the website
    urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/login"]
                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSString *post = @"username=myname&password=mypassword";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Start the connection request
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}
```

Here, when I log the response, it is incomplete.. It is landing in a page that is between the final SUCCESS page.. So the authentication is partially complete..Do I need to include any delay? Please help..

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Connection success.");
    NSURLResponse *responseTest;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *responseDataTest = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest       returningResponse:&responseTest error:&error];

    NSString *responsestring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseDataTest encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Recieved response.. %@",responsestring);
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have been the victim of a HTTP 300 redirect status.

Comment: Thanks for the comment..But when I look at the connection status code in connectionDidFinishLoading, it shows HTTP 201.. How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Try using this method instead. According to the docs it is "Sent when the connection has received sufficient data to construct the URL response for its request. (required)"

Comment: I still see the same response (partially logged in webpage is fetched) in 'didReceiveResponse' method..It stops at that point and does not move forward to the success page..What might be preventing it to move forward? Is it the content of the webpage that is affecting it? Just fyi - the page just has <meta> tags in it, no <body>..Any thoughts?

Comment: I resolved the issue by parsing the forwarding url in the <meta> tag and made a request to that URL to successfully complete the authentication. I am marking David's response as an answer as I was able to get the response and from thereon, I figured out a way to resolve this issue.. Thanks for your comments..